# mapping text to buttons from within a method

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button, findviewbyid

I'm in the very early stages of developing this android app, and I'm trying to setText to buttons from within a method. Doing it not in a method is fine, but I want to call the method over and over. However when I try to create the method to do this, I get a "Non-static method findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context" error.

eg: Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText(options[0]);

The findViewById will be red highlighted

```
package com.example.lp1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;
private Button button2;
private Button button3;
private Button button4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int score = 0;
    int count = 3;
    static int getQuestion(){
    ArrayList set = addingThree();
    final int a = (int) set.get(0);
    final int b = (int) set.get(1);
    final int c = (int) set.get(2);
    final int d = (int) set.get(3);
    final int ans = (int) set.get(4);
    String qText = (String) set.get(5);
    String[] options = new String[] {Integer.toString(a),   
    Integer.toString(b),Integer.toString(c),Integer.toString(d)};

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText(options[0]);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setText(options[1]);

    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setText(options[2]);

    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setText(options[3]);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(qText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
        });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
        });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
        });


    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
   }

   static ArrayList addingThree(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numa = rand.nextInt(99);
    int numb = rand.nextInt(99);
    int numc = rand.nextInt(99);
    int ans = numa + numb + numc;
    int fake1 = rand.nextInt(200) + 50;
    int fake2 = rand.nextInt(200) +50;
    int fake3 = rand.nextInt(200) +50;
    int[ ] options = {fake1, fake2, fake3, ans};

    String stringQuestion = ("What is the sum of " + numa + ", " + numb + ",
    and " + numc + "? ");
    Arrays.sort(options);
    ArrayList parcel = new ArrayList();
    parcel.add(options[0]);
    parcel.add(options[1]);
    parcel.add(options[2]);
    parcel.add(options[3]);
    parcel.add(ans);
    parcel.add(stringQuestion);
    return parcel;
}
```

}

Comment: why you have written static int getQuestion(){??remove static and call the method in oncreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

> static

from your functions.
Also remove the functions from the *onCreate* callback, they don't belong there.

When you're invoking the functions in onCreate, the functions/methods cannot be static

Comment: Nice one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @david You're welcome. Please sign the question as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use findViewById() in static method then make your rootview Global variable